# The button does not respond to the user actions, C# windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am working at a log in system so the users can insert credentials and log in if they are correct by pressing the log in button. For an unknown reason, that button does not respond even if I have the right code for it.

```
private void buttonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB1.Text == "Admin" && TB2.Text == "Admin")
        {
            Chef chef = new Chef();
            MessageBox.Show("You've been logged in successfully as a Chef");
            this.Hide();
            chef.Show();
        }            
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Credentials");
        }
    }
```

[Button properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWs6V.png)

Comment: Click on the lightning bolt tab and make sure that the "Click" event is tied to this method.

Comment: there are no errors, I can run the program just fine, I have the "using system.IO" and still nothing. Next to that button I have another button just to swap to another page and it works just fine.

Comment: Make sure you actually add an event listener to the button. As @RonBeyer says: Click the bolt!